# Downloading pdf from URL with urllib (getting weird html output instead)

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, iframe, urllib

I am trying to download pdfs from several pdf urls.
An example: https://www.fasb.org/page/showpdf?path=0001-%201700-UFI%20AICPA%20ACSEC%20Hanson.pdf

This url directly opens into the PDF on my browser.
However, when I use this code to download it using the link, it returns an HTML file given below.

```
link = "https://www.fasb.org/page/showpdf?path=0001-%201700-UFI%20AICPA%20ACSEC%20Hanson.pdf" 
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, f"/content/drive/MyDrive/Research/pdfs/1.pdf")
```

The resulting "pdf" file or HTML code file is downloaded instead:

[image]

How do I solve this issue? Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: The source shows you the real source of the pdf file, use that

Comment: How do I access this source link automatically? I have about 257 such URLs.

Comment: You've already tagged web scraping and iframe, try using beautifulsoup etc

Comment: maybe download few files and check if all use the same `https://d2x...` so you could replace this part in original url for all PDF to download them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to find `<iframe>` and get `src` - and use it to download file

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://www.fasb.org/page/showpdf?path=0001-%201700-UFI%20AICPA%20ACSEC%20Hanson.pdf'

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BS(response.read(), 'html.parser')

iframe = soup.find('iframe')
url = iframe['src']

filename = urllib.parse.unquote(url)
filename = filename.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

---

Eventually you can check few file to see if all use the same `https://d2x0djib3vzbzj.cloudfront.net/` and simply replace it in url.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://www.fasb.org/page/showpdf?path=0001-%201700-UFI%20AICPA%20ACSEC%20Hanson.pdf'

url = url.replace('https://www.fasb.org/page/showpdf?path=', 
                  'https://d2x0djib3vzbzj.cloudfront.net/')

filename = urllib.parse.unquote(url)
filename = filename.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```